# How do I create a JavaScript service for a PhoneGap based webOS app?

Tags: node.js, cordova, webos

I'm trying to build a webOS 3.0.2 app using PhoneGap 1.0. I'm doing my best to avoid webOS-specific things, but my app does need to run a javascript service when on a webOS device.

I can't find any documentation on how to create and package a simple JavaScript service in this situation. HP's documentation doesn't mention services when dealing with PhoneGap, and PhoneGap's documentation doesn't mention webOS services at all. The 'Hello World' service described in HP's documentation seems to have been written for webOS 2.0, and pulls in large swaths of webOS-specific code -- exactly what I'mn trying to avoid by using PhoneGap in the first place.

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

node.js-powered services on HP webOS are accessed through the service bus.  The PhoneGap 1.0 code on webOS declares a constructor called Service for accessing this bus -- you can see how it's used by looking in the phonegap-1.0.0.js file at definitions of calls like Sms.prototype.send.